# Decode json and do a foreach to get value of each array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am new to PHP, I have the following JSON and I want to print value of each array.

**JSON**

```
[
  ["38", "App Name1", "Long description.", "http:\/\/url.com", "5"],
  ["12", "Name 2", "Long description goes here...", "http:\/\/test.com", "100"]
]
```

I want it to be printed as:

```
App Name 1
Long description
http://url.com
5

Name 2
Long description goes here...
http://test.com
100
```

I am unable to get it to work. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: That isn't a valid json structure; it's an array with two nested arrays.

Comment: @isim this is what i got using json_encode

Comment: Compile your json here http://jsonlint.com/ .. this is not a valid json

Comment: This is valid JSON.  An array contains values, and values can be arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$a='[
    ["38", "App Name1", "Long description.", "http:\/\/url.com", "5"
    ],
    ["12", "Name 2", "Long description goes here...", "http:\/\/test.com", "100"
        ]    
    ]';
$ja=json_decode($a);
if(count($ja)>0)foreach($ja as $jv){
    echo $jv[1]."<br/>";
    echo $jv[2]."<br/>";
    echo $jv[3]."<br/>";
    echo $jv[4]."<br/><br/>";
}

output:

App Name1
Long description.
http://url.com
5

Name 2
Long description goes here...
http://test.com
100
```